# In a webpack app, I need to ask IntelliJ to add the ./app directory as basePath for import

Tags: node.js, reactjs, intellij-idea, ide, webpack

I am working on a webpack, nodejs and react application.

I am trying to enable an import feature in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.

I wan't all the `import` from my `./app` directory to be 'linked'.

By 'linked' I mean that I can enter a method by using `CTRL`+`LEFT CLICK` or an import by doing `CTRL`+`LEFT CLICK` on the string responsible for the import.

So far, this feature work fine for `node_modules` and relative import, I need it also for the `./app` folder

Is there a way to ask IntelliJ to found my javascript single page application under the `./app` folder so the `import` with webpack can be `ctrl+clicked` (enter in file)

Comment: Switch your code to `JSX` harmony when IDE prompts.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I did switch to JSX harmony, I've also set up this so no one get prompt for this message. What does it have to do with my question ?

Comment: I thought your `node-modules` are not detected in your `idea` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible *in March 2017* to configure import path in IDEA IntelliJ for a webpack 2.0 project.

There is an issue open if you wish to track it's status : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17254

You could try to write your application in the project directory, sorry.